# After installing SQL*Plus, how do I find out the default username and password in my 20.04 ubuntu?

Tags: server, 20.04, mysql, database

Results of the `sqlplus` command:

[image: results of sqlplus command run]

Comment: Googling turns up several possibilities, most often "sysdba" and "oracle". Which ones have you tried?

Comment: @Jos Not working sir

Comment: What does "Oracle Support" say?

Comment: Ask the person who installed the database.